# Fixed postion for elements in sql reporting services

Tags: reporting-services

I'm using sql report 2005. I have a text box with CanGrow=True and few text boxes beneath it. as the top textbox grows other text boxes are pushed down. What I want to do is preventing some of the text boxes from changing position.
Is there a way to make element positions absolute like HTML for example?